# Passing a character variable into a function in R (Tidyjson)

Tags: json, r

I'm messing around with `tidyjson` (latest from github, published by Jeremy Stanley). I wanted to sort of automate searching and extract the nested arrays. The following examples below provide the output I want.

```
'{"name": {"first": "bob", "last": "jones"}, "age": 32}' %>%
 enter_object("name") %>%
 gather_keys %>% 
 append_values_string

'{"name": {"first": "bob", "last": "jones"}, "age": 32}' %>% 
 enter_object(name) %>% 
 gather_keys %>% 
 append_values_string
```

These both give the same output:

```
# A tbl_json: 2 x 3 tibble with a "JSON" attribute
`attr(., "JSON")` document.id   key string
          <chr>       <int> <chr>  <chr>
1             "bob"           1 first    bob
2           "jones"           1  last  jones
```

However, if I declare a character variable before and pass it along it fails.

```
object_name <- "name"
'{"name": {"first": "bob", "last": "jones"}, "age": 32}' %>% 
enter_object(list(name="name")) %>% 
gather_keys %>% 
append_values_string

Error: Path components must be single names or character strings
```

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with Hadley's book [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), this is a piece of non-standard evaluation that unfortunately does not presently have a workaround in pure `tidyjson` (I would prefer a `enter_object_` that uses standard evaluation, more like `dplyr`).  I am hopeful of that functionality at some point being available, because as you suggest, it would be nice to vectorize and automate these sorts of programs.

The Non-Standard Evaluation is the "magic" that allows you to pass in the un-quoted `name` and still get good results in your second example (instead of the program looking for an object called `name`).  The hazard is it does not resolve objects like `object_name` in your case.

That said, it seems you can work-around with `do.call` and a list of parameters (I fixed your example, as I think it went a bit awry)

```
library(tidyjson)

json <- "{\"name\": {\"first\": \"bob\", \"last\": \"jones\"}, \"age\": 32}"
object_name <- "name"

do.call(enter_object, args = list(json, object_name)) %>% gather_object %>% 
  append_values_string
#> # A tbl_json: 2 x 3 tibble with a "JSON" attribute
#>   `attr(., "JSON")` document.id  name string
#>               <chr>       <int> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1         "\"bob\""           1 first    bob
#> 2       "\"jones\""           1  last  jones
```

I definitely recommend checking out some of the new features / functionality in the development version of `tidyjson` with `devtools::install_github('jeremystan/tidyjson')`, but unfortunately no support for standard evaluation in "path"s yet.